# Capistrano: How to set global environment variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, capistrano

I need to find a way to set global env variable from Capistrano. Actual value is generated on in runtime, I can not check it in the repo and load from there.

This value must be loaded as `ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID']` in one initializer.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you use the `default_environment` capistrano variable ?
cf [github/capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb#LC258)

For instance, we can use it for rbenv in production :

```
set :default_environment, {
'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}
```

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 3):

How about just specifying it in your initializer?

```
ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID'] = 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

If by global variable you mean something that is generated in Capistrano and later used in Rails then yes, you will have to create some sort of file. Ruby variables do not persist between runs. Environment variables can be set but only apply to sub-processes.

One way to dump a file on the server during your deployment is like what you have there, only remote:

```
run "echo #{asset_version} > #{release_path}/config/asset_version.conf"
```

You can later pick up and read that value as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I'm using this method so far:

```
desc 'My custom task'
task :task_foo do
  asset_version = 12345
  system "echo #{asset_version} > RAILS_ASSET_ID"
end
```

and it is retrieved in intializer :

```
File.open(Rails.root.join 'RAILS_ASSET_ID').read.strip]
```

But there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Better way: `echo #{asset_version} >>  #{current_path}/config/initializers/asset_version.rb`

Comment: Why would you want to append to a file over and over without clearing out the old value?

Comment: Every cap deploy creates a new dir structure, so the file _should not_ be there. The `>>` is a safety mechanism, in case a developer one day creates that file.